# Find string array name in strings.xml using string item in it - android

Tags: android, arrays, string

I have a requirement wherein I need to find the array name using item present in it. Sounds confusing!

I have array as below.

```
<string-array name="numbers_content">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
    <item>Five</item>
    <item>Six</item>
    <item>Seven</item>
    <item>Eight</item>
    <item>Nine</item>
    <item>Ten</item>
    <item>Twenty</item>
    <item>Thirty</item>
    <item>Forty</item>
    <item>Fifty</item>
    <item>Sixty</item>
    <item>Seventy</item>
    <item>Eighty</item>
    <item>Ninety</item>
    <item>Hundred</item>
    <item>Two Hundred</item>
    <item>Three Hundred</item>
    <item>Four Hundred</item>
    <item>Five Hundred</item>
    <item>One Thousand</item>
    <item>One Lakh</item>
    <item>One Crore</item>
</string-array>
```

I get a string as an argument to the method as below

```
getParentArray(String value){
//Consider the value received is "Five" and the output should be the array name which is numbers_content
//here I need the help in knowing how to do it.
}
```

How to write a method to fetch the array name?

Comment: `arrays` are static

Comment: What if the "Five" contains in multiple arrays ?

Comment: assume it exists only in one array @theapache64

Comment: What do you really want to achieve with this ? Maybe some other approach can be more suited

Comment: @VivekMishra Basically I need to do this. I have two arrays. I get input to the method a string which will be present in one array and I need to return item at the same index in the other array. Ideally, I want to map two string arrays. Now, when I get the input, I will not know which array it is in. that's where the complexity lies in. There are tens of paired arrays like this. I may get a string which lies in any of the arrays. (One string exists only in one array - no repetitions)

Comment: What have you tried, so far? I mean, do you know how to get a resource array in code? If so, do you know how to loop over an array, and compare values?

Comment: The problem is in finding which array the item lies in. I want to know if it's possible or not. Once found, the next steps I can take care of.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Start with one array – e.g., `String[] numbers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.numbers_content);` – then loop over `numbers`, and if you find a match, it's in `numbers_content`.

Comment: @MikeM. understand your solution. But the problem is that there is not just one array. There are a lot of arrays and the method will just get a string. Considering there are 10 arrays, it is not good to scan through all to find it right.

Comment: You only have to look until you find a match. Other than that, how else did you think you could do this? Something, somewhere, is going to have to loop over values until a match is found, and, AFAIK, there's no built-in resource method for it. I mean, you could use some standard data structures to make your job easier – e.g., a `Map` of `List`s, like a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` – but ultimately, something's looping.

Comment: @VarunAM I've posted an answer. Please check if it fits your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no built-in method available for your requirement. So, I've created a simple solution.

I've created a `ArrayStorage` class

```
class ArrayStorage(private val context: Context) {

    private val storage = mutableMapOf<Int, Array<String>>()

    fun add(arrayName: Int) {
        val arr = context.resources.getStringArray(arrayName)
        storage[arrayName] = arr
    }

    fun getArrayName(value: String): String? {
        var storageArrayName: String? = null
        for (arr in storage) {
            for (item in arr.value) {
                if (item == value) {
                    storageArrayName = context.resources.getResourceEntryName(arr.key)
                    break
                }
            }

            if (storageArrayName != null) {
                break
            }
        }
        return storageArrayName
    }

}
```

The `add` method adds items to the storage, and the `getArrayName` method can be used to find the array name of the the containing array. If the element is not found, `null` will be returned.

**Example**

*Data*

```xml
<string-array name="numbers_content">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
    <item>Five</item>
    <item>Six</item>
    <item>Seven</item>
    <item>Eight</item>
    <item>Nine</item>
    <item>Ten</item>
    <item>Twenty</item>
    <item>Thirty</item>
    <item>Forty</item>
    <item>Fifty</item>
    <item>Sixty</item>
    <item>Seventy</item>
    <item>Eighty</item>
    <item>Ninety</item>
    <item>Hundred</item>
    <item>Two Hundred</item>
    <item>Three Hundred</item>
    <item>Four Hundred</item>
    <item>Five Hundred</item>
    <item>One Thousand</item>
    <item>One Lakh</item>
    <item>One Crore</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="name_content">
    <item>Jake Wharton</item>
    <item>John Doe</item>
    <item>James Albert</item>
</string-array>
```

**Usage**

```
val arrayStorage = ArrayStorage(this)
arrayStorage.add(R.array.numbers_content)
arrayStorage.add(R.array.name_content)

Log.d("TAG", "ArrayName = ${ arrayStorage.getArrayName("Five") }")
```

**Output**

```
ArrayName = numbers_content
```

**NOTE:**

If you want to return the array identifier (Int) rather than array name (String), replace

```
context.resources.getResourceEntryName(arr.key)
```

with `arr.key`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It serves the purpose.